# how to start new activity via gridview onitemclick?

Tags: android, gridview, start-activity

i want to open new activity **on itemclick listner** in gridview.like this. 
Click position 1(india) ->open activity 1.Click position 2(brazil)->open activity 2.Click position 3(canada)->open activity 3.
how to possible it?
This is my code.

```
   android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener; 
public class GridViewExampleActivity extends Activity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */

private GridviewAdapter mAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> listCountry;
private ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;

private GridView gridView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    prepareList();

    // prepared arraylist and passed it to the Adapter class
    mAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(this,listCountry, listFlag);

    // Set custom adapter to gridview
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Implement On Item click listener
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(GridViewExampleActivity.this, mAdapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

public void prepareList()
{
      listCountry = new ArrayList<String>();

      listCountry.add("india");
      listCountry.add("Brazil");
      listCountry.add("Canada");
      listCountry.add("China");


      listFlag = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      listFlag.add(R.drawable.india);
      listFlag.add(R.drawable.brazil);
      listFlag.add(R.drawable.canada);
      listFlag.add(R.drawable.china);



}
}
```

Thanks !!

Comment: you can compare with position in onItemClick.

Comment: Do you want to open same activity or different activity on each item click?

Comment: @Newbie Android, i want to open different activity on click different item

Comment: @Dhirajkumar Patil edited my answer just check.

Comment: Thanks to all. Now i try all answers;)

Comment: Thanks to all again. And sorry for i cant accept all answers.but i can upvote your answers.but my problem is i have no minimum 15 point. Sorry to all:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open activity using intent based on position

```
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                        long arg3) {
                    if(position==1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(GridViewExampleActivity.this, IndiaActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else if(position==2)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(GridViewExampleActivity.this, BrazilActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                    Toast.makeText(GridViewExampleActivity.this, mAdapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I just edit                   if(position==0) {
                            Intent intent = new      Intent(GridViewExampleActivity.this, IndiaActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else if(position==1)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(GridViewExampleActivity.this, BrazilActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }            thank you;)

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this code in your OnItemClickListener
there are two ways to do this. If you have the same layout but different content then you can only create one activity and put extras and change the content. If you have different design for layout, then use this,

```
 switch (position) {
 case 0:
   Intent intent = new Intent(GridViewExampleActivity.this,ActivityOne.class);
  break;
 case 1:
  Intent intent = new Intent(GridViewExampleActivity.this,ActivityTwo.class);
  break;
}

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can compare with position.

```
switch (listCountry.get(position)) {
   case 0:
      Intent intent = new Intent(GridViewExampleActivity.this,IndiaActivity.class);
      break;
   case 1:
      intent = new Intent(GridViewExampleActivity.this,BrazilActivity.class);
      break;
}
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting any activity is exactly same in every situation. You just create an intent and supply it to startActivity() method.

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        if(position == 1) {
            // start activity for India
            startActivity(new Intent(GridViewExampleActivity.this, InidaActivity.class));
         } else if(position == 2) {
            // start activity for Brazil
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your grid item click listener start the activity

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(GridViewExampleActivity.this, mAdapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(GridViewExampleActivity.this , YourDetailsActivity.class)
            intent.putExtra("country", listCountry.get(position);
            intent.putExtra("flag", listFlag.get(position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and in your detail activity get data from intent like this

in onCreate()

```
country = (String)getIntent().getExtra().get("country");
flag = (int)getIntent().getExtra().get("flag");
```

in your details activity you can check country selected and set data accordingly

```
if(country.equals("india")){
    // Show data related to india
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with country name also

```
switch (listCountry.get(position)) {


 case "India":
      Intent intent = new Intent(GridViewExampleActivity.this,IndiaActivity.class);
      break;
   case "Brazil":
      Intent intent = new Intent(GridViewExampleActivity.this,BrazilActivity.class);
      break;
   }
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code -

```
  gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {

    switch (position) {

    case 0:
                   //Use some different intent here
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("id", position);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;

    case 1:
            //Use some different intent here

    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
                    j.putExtra("id", position);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
    case 2:
                //Use some different intent here

    Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
                    k.putExtra("id", position);
                    startActivity(k);
                    break;
    case 3:
            //Use some different intent here

    Intent l = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
                    l.putExtra("id", position);
                    startActivity(l);
                    break;

    default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Here's you can see more explained code.

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-simple-gridview-tutorial/