# Intent only showing constructor with only one parameter

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to start an activity when a button is clicked, but the problem is android studio is only showing one constructor!
I want to use the constructor with two parameters as follows: [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9WNk.jpg)

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, myActivityName.class);
```

Note: `Intent` has been imported.

Comment: Show us some code samples you tried so far

Comment: Share your code along with imports

Comment: use your_activity_name.this instead of using only this.

Comment: "`Intent`" has been imported? All Android classes are "imported" - what does this mean? And you did not post the error for trying with two parameters but sometimes the IDE will show errors but they will disappear after a build attempt. Or it could be another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call new Intent with two parameters and it should work. Just because AS isn't showing the constructor signature doesn't mean it isn't there.

As mentioned above you also need to call

```
Intent(YourActivityName.this, myActivityName.class);
```

Instead of

```
Intent(this, myActivityName.class);
```

The `this` in the latter case will be referring to the anonymous class you created to implement the OnClickListener interface

Comment: what error it shows.Add the error details in your question or as a comment then it will give more responses

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can write. If you can't please upload image with elaborated setonitemclicklistener and the error that is underlined with red line.

Useful links:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

[how to start new activity via gridview onitemclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561813/how-to-start-new-activity-via-gridview-onitemclick)

Answer (score 0):

In that screenshot, the text in parentheses is *not* documentation of the constructor parameters, it is the package definition for the class. In this particular case, it is telling you that the `Intent` class on the first line is part of the `android.content` package.

This isn't super helpful in your case, but in other cases it will help you differentiate between two classes with the same name. For example, you might see

- `Date (java.util)`
- `Date (java.sql)`
- ...

---

If you have correctly imported `android.content.Intent`, and Android Studio is still giving you an error when you try to use the constructor you want, I assume the problem is that you are passing the wrong arguments to the constructor. It is very easy to accidentally write this:

> ```
> Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class);
> ```

When you are inside of an anonymous inner class, like an `OnItemClickListener`, the `this` keyword actually refers to the click listener, and not your activity. However, you can qualify the `this` keyword to get the behavior you want:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(VegetablesViewActivity.this, MyOtherActivity.class);
```